# Unit test for sort of random List<Object>

Tags: unit-testing, sorting, java-7, junit4, easymock

I have a class who's only task is to take a `List<Object>` and return a sorted `List<Object>`. For an example the sort method in the class works with a procedure which places the Objects randomly in the list.

**Trying to do:** to write the test for that sorting method (or class) which must fail if the sorting is in fact just random. That means I need to find the `List<Object>` order to test I assume.

**Code to be tested**

```
class RootLoggerFirstSorter {

List<LoggerConfig> sort(List<LoggerConfig> unSortedList) {

    List<LoggerConfig> levelSortedList = new ArrayList<>(unSortedList);

    Collections.sort(levelSortedList, new Comparator<LoggerConfig>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(LoggerConfig o1, LoggerConfig o2) {
            if (o1.getLevel().intLevel() == o2.getLevel().intLevel()) {
                return 0;
            } else if (o1.getLevel().intLevel() < o2.getLevel().intLevel()) {
                return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }}
    );

    LinkedList<LoggerConfig> sortedList = new LinkedList<LoggerConfig>();
    for(Iterator<LoggerConfig> i = levelSortedList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        LoggerConfig cfg = i.next();
        addNextLoggerConfig(cfg, sortedList);
    }
    return sortedList;
}

private void addNextLoggerConfig(LoggerConfig cfg, LinkedList<LoggerConfig> sortedList) {

    if(cfg.getName() == null || cfg.getName().isEmpty()) {
        sortedList.addFirst(cfg);
    } else {
        sortedList.addLast(cfg);
    }
}
}
```

**Tried**

```
    .....
    expect(item1.getLevel()).andStubReturn(Level.DEBUG);
    expect(item2.getLevel()).andStubReturn(Level.ERROR);
    expect(item3.getLevel()).andStubReturn(Level.INFO);
    .....
 //Ignore the pre req for test setup 
    @Test
public void testSort() {

    List<LoggerConfig> unsortedList = makeUnsortedList();
    EasyMock.replay(item1,item2,item3);

    List<LoggerConfig> sortedList = tested.sort(unsortedList);

    assertThat("First item on the list is ERROR level: ", sortedList.get(0).getLevel(), is(Level.ERROR) );
    assertTrue(sortedList.get(1).getLevel().equals(Level.INFO) || sortedList.get(1).getLevel().equals(Level.INFO));
    assertTrue(sortedList.get(2).getLevel().equals(Level.DEBUG) || sortedList.get(2).getLevel().equals(Level.DEBUG));
}
```

But this test will always pass since if looked at the index 1 and 2 only, index 0 will always contain the LoggerConfig with an empty name [set up is done that way]). So I thought **Should I just unit test the compare method instead?** If yes, how?

**Problem** The issue is that I need to test the sort method with a particular Object property which is the level of the `LoggerConfig` object. So the test must check the `List` order.

Comment: Either your question is confusing or it's just me... What exactly is the problem? Normally you would write a test method for each testcase, for example "list in reverse order should be sorted correctly". In this method, you prepare the list, sort it and then check the ordering... I don't quite understand where you are having problems...

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Since I do not know the integer values of the log levels used in the sorting, I need to discover this in order to test successfully. However, the test should of course still test that the sorting is done. So there are two tests required. So my `testSort()` doesn't test the intended functionality which must return an ordered list and not random.

Comment: Still confused. If yo need to know the log levels, look into the code. Should be stated there. In your test, it's completely ok to rely on the fact that the log level is, for example, 700...

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz What happens in the test is that any order is accepted. I am checking that the level is either DEBUG or INFO which is trivially true. Hence this passes. But I have to test that "any order of the list is not accepted"

Comment: Why are you saying that you have to sort a `List<Object>`, when you are actually sorting a `List<LoggerConfig>`?

Comment: @Holger to generalize the concept.

Answer (score 2):

Many different aspects here:

- Of course you do not need to test the **built-in** Collections.sort() method.
- In that sense: instead, you want to test two aspects A) that you are actually calling that sort method B) that your comparator works as expected.

A) is achieved by the code you put in your own answer. Or to be precise: you *only* need one test case where you sort check for an expected result; after providing a specific test input to your method.

B) is achieved by writing test code that simply checks that compareTo() returns the expected result for the different input

In the end, this is about *properly* dissecting your logic into classes. Of course you *can* declare that comparator as anonymous inner class; and just verify that the sort method returns the expected result.

But when you make the comparator, say an inner class somewhere, you could write unit tests for just the comparator functionality.

Finally: your test case does **not** mean the goal that you *stated*: *must fail if the sorting is in fact just random*. You see, if the result of sort() is *random*, that it could *randomly* give you a correct result.  Meaning: you can't expect a single test to verify "possibly random behavior". You would have to run many tests with a lot of different data, and verify that **all** of them pass; to achieve a certain *confidence* that the sort() isnt pure random.

But as said: you are not sorting. You are calling the built-in sort method which does **not** need to be tested.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just unit test the compare method instead?

No, you should not. The test may fail if you try to refactor the sort method later. You are actually trying to assert that the sorting is done probably. The compare method is just an implementation detail. You may not use the compare method to sort the list in the future.

Of course you also don't need to test the built-in sort method because you are actually testing your custom sort method. Anything inside this sort method is implementation details including the list.sort method you called. You should pretend that you don't know about it when you are writing a test.

Other than that, your sort method also contain some logic that is not related to the built-in sort method.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed the `List<ConfigLogger>` followed something like `item1["", ERROR], item2["com.fwk.foo", DEBUG], item3["com.fwk.core.baa", INFO]`. So in that case I needed to check that if item3 is in the position 1 and item2 is in position 3 in the list the implementation does the sort correctly. So test I needed was as follows:

```
    @Test
    public void testSort() {
    List<LoggerConfig> unsortedList = makeUnsortedList();
    EasyMock.replay(item1,item2,item3);

    List<LoggerConfig> sortedList = tested.sort(unsortedList);

    assertFalse(unsortedList.equals(sortedList));
    assertTrue(sortedList.get(0).getName().isEmpty());

    LoggerConfig cfg1 = sortedList.get(1);
    LoggerConfig cfg2 = sortedList.get(2);

    assertThat(cfg1.getLevel(), is(Level.DEBUG));
    assertThat(cfg2.getLevel(), is(Level.INFO));
}
```

So I am accessing the item from the list and comparing if they are same as expected.